# How do I fix this bound mismatch error?

Tags: java, generics, casting, header, compareto

by `<Item>` it's saying : -

```
Bound mismatch: The type Item is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends 
 Comparable<? super T>> of the type ExpandableArrayList<T>

ExpandableArrayList<Item> items = new ExpandableArrayList<Item> ();
```

These are my headers:

```
public interface ListInterface <T extends Comparable <? super T>>
public class ExpandableArrayList<T extends Comparable<?super T>>  extends Item {
public class Item implements Comparable
```

I can't figure out what I need to change exactly. Every time I change something in one header other errors pop up.  I use the compareTo(Object obj)  type.

Comment: And what could be an ExpandableArrayList class? Could you provide more code please?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Item` class is implementing the raw form of the `Comparable` interface.  You should have it implement the generic form, by declaring a type parameter on `Item` itself.  Then, `ExpandableArrayList` can implement the generic form of `Item`.

```
public class Item<T extends Comparable <? super T>> implements Comparable<T>
```

and

```
public ExpandableArrayList<T extends Comparable<?super T>>  extends Item<T>
```

This will resolve compilation problems due to the headers.

But it's unclear why an `ExpandableArrayList` should subclass `Item`.  It should contain `Item`s; this fails the "is-a" test.  `ExpandableArrayList` shouldn't extend `Item` at all.